# C/C++ library for VTK IO

Tags: c++, c, file-io, vtk

I have a simulation in C++ which generates huge amount of data. Right now I am using MATLAB libraries to save the results as a .mat file, but eventually I will be needing an open source binary format. I don't want to implement my own binary format and ASCII is not an option. I heard that VTK provides .vtk binary file format for saving 3d data structures, which is exactly what I need. Is there a good C/C++ library for reading/writing VTK files?

Comment: I think it would help if you more clearly specified what the data is. It sounds (from the latter part of the question) as the data is 3D, but is it actual model/geometry data, i.e. vertices and polygons?

Comment: The data are 3-D vector field on a 2-D plane. Simply put, the domain is 2-D plane and the range is 3-D vector. But I don't think it is relevant to the question in anyway though!

Comment: mat is an pretty much an open source binary format. It is just HDF5 plus a fairly useless header. See [here](https://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27350-c++-class-to-write-hdf5-mat-files) and also [here](https://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23416-writetovtk). Note the latter uses the inefficient text-based VTK format.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a good library providing .vtk files I/O, and it is called... wait for it... VTK! :)

http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/4.2/html/classvtkUnstructuredGridWriter.html

http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/4.2/html/classvtkUnstructuredGridReader.html

(There are many other readers/writers to suit your data type).

Comment: BTW, VTK isn't always the best file format... consider using HDF5:

http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/

Comment: .mat *is* HDF5. I agree though it is easier to read .mat from your non-matlab program than to write VTK from matlab.

Comment: Could you name some of those many other readers, as VTK might be a bit heavy just for using VTK I/O.